# html bold tag ignored by browser using php

Tags: php, jquery, html, string, echo

i have got a ajax script that inputs data into a sql table, and on submit i provide a modal with a message that displays $name of the person i am having trouble with echoing the $name variable with the bold tag in php

here is how i am using the echo statment in my php file

```
echo "Thank you <b>'$name'</b> for submitting your details. This has now   been saved in our registry.";
```

and then i use the following to set the text of the p tag in the modal dialog

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: $(form).attr('action'),
        data: formData
        }).done(function(response) {
           $(formMessages).text(response);
          showModal();
});
```

when the modal displays i am getting "Thank you for `<b>`Mike Stevens`</b>` for submitting your details...."

it seems the browser is ignoring the `<b>` tag or i am missing something in the echo statement

thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use .html() to set html content to $(formMessages). If you use .text, it will be automatically escaped for you and html shows up as plain text.

Change your javascript to:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: $(form).attr('action'),
    data: formData
    }).done(function(response) {
       $(formMessages).html(response);
      showModal();
});
```